# Concisely declare and initialize a multi-dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++

For example in 3 dimensions, I would normally do something like

```cpp
vector<vector<vector<T>>> v(x, vector<vector<T>>(y, vector<T>(z, val)));
```

However this gets tedious for complex types and in large dimensions. Is it possible to define a type, say, `tensor`, whose usage would be like so:

```
tensor<T> t(x, y, z, val1);
t[i][j][k] = val2;
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just flatten it to 1D and use indexing like `vec[i*rows+j]`?

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question as to the cleanest way of doing this, and using that type of indexing is very error prone. Would it be possible to define a method that takes an index for each dimension and returns the element there (so you don't necessarily have to overload the `[]` operator)?

Comment: You can write a simple class that holds the 1D vector and overrides `operator()` with N arguments to handle the indexing easily enough.

Comment: How would it know how many parameters to take?

Comment: A vector of a vector of a vector is very inefficient, as it gives triple indirection. Will this not just fit in an array? Anyhow these design questions are very old, and there are a number of libraries that have become very good at this, e.g. Boost UBLAS or Eigen. Also look at the new linear algebra proposal for C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with template metaprogramming.

Define a vector `NVector`

```cpp
template<int D, typename T>
struct NVector : public vector<NVector<D - 1, T>> {
    template<typename... Args>
    NVector(int n = 0, Args... args) : vector<NVector<D - 1, T>>(n, NVector<D - 1, T>(args...)) {
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct NVector<1, T> : public vector<T> {
    NVector(int n = 0, const T &val = T()) : vector<T>(n, val) {
    }
};
```

You can use it like this

```cpp
    const int n = 5, m = 5, k = 5;
    NVector<3, int> a(n, m, k, 0);
    cout << a[0][0][0] << '\n';
```

I think it's clear how it can be used. Let's still say `NVector<# of dimensions, type> a(lengths of each dimension separated by coma (optional)...,  default value (optional))`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer shows a good way of making a vector of vectors with template metaprogramming. If you want a multidimensional array data structure with fewer allocations and contiguous storage underneath, here is an example of how to achieve that with an NDArray template class wrapping access to an underlying vector. This could be extended to define non-default `operator=`, copy operators, debug bounds checking per dimension, row-major or column-major storage, etc for extra convenience.

**NDArray.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <vector>

template<int N, typename ValueType>
class NDArray {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    NDArray(Args... args)
    : dims({ args... }),
      offsets(compute_offsets(dims)),
      data(compute_size(dims), ValueType{})
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N, 
            "Incorrect number of NDArray dimension arguments");
    }

    void fill(ValueType val) {
        std::fill(data.begin(), data.end(), val);
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    inline void resize(Args... args) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N,
            "Incorrect number of NDArray resize arguments");
        dims = { args... };
        offsets = compute_offsets(dims);
        data.resize(compute_size(dims));
        fill(ValueType{});
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    inline ValueType operator()(Args... args) const {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N, 
            "Incorrect number of NDArray index arguments");
        return data[calc_index({ args... })];
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    inline ValueType& operator()(Args... args) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N, 
            "Incorrect number of NDArray index arguments");
        return data[calc_index({ args... })];
    }

    int length(int axis) const { return dims[axis]; }

    const int num_dims = N;

private:
    static std::array<int, N> compute_offsets(const std::array<int, N>& dims) {
        std::array<int, N> offsets{};
        offsets[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
            offsets[i] = offsets[i - 1] * dims[i - 1];
        }
        return offsets;
    }

    static int compute_size(const std::array<int, N>& dims) {
        int size = 1;
        for (auto&& d : dims) size *= d;
        return size;
    }

    inline int calc_index(const std::array<int, N>& indices) const {
        int idx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) idx += offsets[i] * indices[i];
        return idx;
    }

    std::array<int, N> dims;
    std::array<int, N> offsets;
    std::vector<ValueType> data;
};
```

This overrides the `operator()` with the correct number of arguments, and won't compile if the wrong number of arguments is given. Some example use

```cpp
using Array2D = NDArray<2,double>;
using Array3D = NDArray<3,double>;

auto a = Array2D(3, 6);
a.fill(1.0);
a(2, 4) = 2.0;
//a(2,4,4) will not compile
std::cout << "a = " << std::endl << a << std::endl;

a.resize(2,2);
a(1,1) = 1.2;
std::cout << "a = " << std::endl << a << std::endl;

//auto b = Array3D(4, 4); // will not compile

auto b = Array3D(4, 3, 2);
b.fill(-1.0);
b(0, 0, 0) = 4.0;
b(1, 1, 1) = 2.0;
std::cout << "b = " << std::endl << b << std::endl;
```

(using helper output methods for 2D and 3D arrays)

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array2D& arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(0); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length(1); ++j) {
            os << arr(i,j) << " ";
        }
        os << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array3D& arr) {
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(2); ++k) {
        os << "array(:,:,"<<k<<") = " << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(0); ++i) {
            os << "  ";
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length(1); ++j) {
                os << arr(i, j, k) << " ";
            }
            os << std::endl;
        }
        os << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```